# Copy one dimensional array across two dimensions without repeating the values in Excel

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, vba

I am retrieving the 10 biggest rows from a SQL table in Excel. Sometimes there are more than one row, sometimes there is only one row.

The results are displayed in a range of cells with an array formula. My problem being that when only one row is returned by the SQL query, that row is copied vertically over the range.

Here is a simplified print screen of my issue using static named ranges:

---

### [image: one dimensional arrays copied accross]

I don't want the repetition to happen. This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Any idea?

**EDIT**

This is the code that generates the array of my cells:

```
=SQL("SELECT IT_Project_Name, SUM(Oct), SUM(YTD)
      FROM SD_Source.sdSourceCells
      GROUP BY IT_Project_Name
      ORDER BY SUM(Oct) DESC")
```

SQL being a custom UDF function that allows me to perform SQL queries on named ranges within my workbook.

A hack that I found to my problem was to put the whole function into a named range and then using =INDEX(). The downside is that the code becomes hardly accessible/editable.

Comment: You need to show your function code...

Comment: So you want to be able to show the contents of a named range - using an array formula - in another range which may not have the same dimensions as the named range? The only way you could do that I think would be to wrap your range name in a UDF which would make the necessary adjustments to fill the destination as you want. Something like `={adjustRange(singleABC)}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Usage: `{=Adjust(singleABC)}`

```
Public Function Adjust(rng As Range)
    Dim c, r, rD, cD, rS, cS, arr, tmp

    rD = Application.Caller.Rows.Count
    cD = Application.Caller.Columns.Count

    rS = rng.Rows.Count
    cS = rng.Columns.Count

    ReDim arr(1 To rD, 1 To cD)

    For r = 1 To rD
    For c = 1 To cD
        If r <= rS And c <= cS Then
            tmp = rng.Cells(r, c).Value
            arr(r, c) = IIf(Len(tmp) > 0, tmp, "")
        Else
            arr(r, c) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        End If
    Next c
    Next r

    Adjust = arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I went for this trick:

```
{=INDEX(singleABC;ROW();COLUMN())}
```

This way I get #REF instead of duplicates when I copy down a single dimensional array.

Thanks for your answers, much appreciated.